# Margin negativo que no responde igual en firefox y webkit

Tags: css

Tengo un icono de fontawesome al que le quiero poner encima un número. El caso es que el número lo he puesto pero difiere un poco cuando lo abres en safari y cuando lo abres en firefox.

este seria el de Safari:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este el de Firefox:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí en las imágenes no se ve demasiado el efecto pero en Safari esta movido hacia la derecha mas que en Firefox.

Esta hecho así:

```css
i { font-size: 25px; }
.CalendarioNum { clear: left; font-weight:900; font-size: 13px; margin-left: -19px; color: #FFF; }
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">


<i class="fas fa-calendar"><span class="CalendarioNum">15</span></i>
```

¿Existe alguna forma de que los valores negativos los interpreten igual todos los navegadores? Es que también me pasa con un `div` que uno sale en su sitio y el otro separado :(

Comment: Quizás sea el tipo de letra ya que veo una fuente diferente en uno y otro navegador. ¿Has definido una fuente?

Comment: Esta puesta para el html completo. Pero voy a probar a forzarle una tipografía. @PedroPrada Pues si. forzando que use la misma tipografía se encaja bien :) Mil gracias...  ¿Me lo pones como respuesta y te doy el ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quizás sea el tipo de letra ya que se ve una fuente diferente en uno y otro navegador. ¿Has definido una fuente?